# localhost:3000 is redirecting to www.localhost in all browsers

Tags: redirection, localhost, hosts-file

This is happening on OS X 10.8 in both Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. There is currently nothing running on port 3000 so I cannot imagine it is related to the Rails project there. It seems to be system wide but I wiped the `etc/hosts` file and flushed the cache.

Comment: Did you try http:// localhost:3000?

Comment: Yes, I found the reason so I'll update in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was Rack. Another developer had added rack middleware that did a 301 redirect for *all* domains to go to `www.#{domain}`